# Get the download progress in Launchpad

Tags: macos, launchpad

I'm downloading Xcode 4.3. It is getting downloaded in Launchpad.

I want to know about the download progress.

Comment: You should see a little progress bar on the left side of your dock (under the launchpad icon). You can also open the app store and see the progress and speed there.

Comment: where should I look in the app store ??

Comment: Wherever you see Xcode listed. Try the "Purchases" tab.

Comment: I tried that too but I am unable to see that thing you are mentioning ..

Comment: Then I don't think you're downloading it. Type "xcode" in the search bar on the top-right of the app store. If you see the Xcode icon and it has the button "install" on it, that means you weren't downloading it. Click that button and put in your itunes password.

Comment: Purchases tab actually shows progress

Answer (score 1):

Goto AppStore, click on Purchase button, find your App and just beside it, their will be progress bar which shows how much is downloaded and how much time it will take to complete the download of your app.

[Source: OSXDaily](http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/27/check-download-progress-mac-app-store/)